# i have a tempermonkey script which read data from csv file .....i want to change it based on fields on webpage

Tags: javascript

The script loads data from a CSV file. Page  sometimes has five fields, 
   sometimes four. The script needs to adjust based on the number of fields.
   forexample I need to modify this tempermonkey script 
    enter 4 pieces of data if there are 4 fields or enter 5 pieces of data if 
     there are 5 fields on the web page.

```
       $(window).ready(function($) {
         var file = GM_getResourceText('csvFile');
         var csv = $.csv.toArrays(file);
         var row = 0;

         //var interval = setInterval(fillFormInterval, 3000);
         var scope = angular.element($('body')).scope();
        // scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(){
        // fillForm(csv[row]);
       //setTimeout(fillForm(csv[row]));
    //});



      var interval = setInterval(fillFormInterval, 1000);
      functionfillFormInterval() {
         if($('#applicant-preferredCommunicationMethod').length) {
             clearInterval(interval);
             setTimeout(function() {
             fillForm(csv[row]);
         },3000);
        }
       }



       functionfillForm(tempRow) {
       var scope = angular.element($('#applicant-firstName')).scope();
       if(!scope.applicant || !scope.applicant.phone1) {
       return;
        }



      var row = new Array(5).fill(undefined);
      row[1] = "NMN";
      tempRow.forEach(function(data,i) {
        if(data != '') {
          row[i] = data;
      }
      });




          scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.applicant.firstName = row[0];
          scope.applicant.middleName = row[1];
          scope.applicant.lastName = row[2];
          scope.applicant.dateOfBirth = row[3];
          scope.applicant.dateOfBirth2 = row[3];
          scope.applicant.phone1.number = row[4];
          scope.applicant.preferredCommunicationMethod = "PHONE1";
          scope.inherited.next();
        });
        //scope.applicant.countryOfBirth = "CD";
       }




         var interval_2 = setInterval(fillFormInterval_2, 1000);
            function fillFormInterval_2() {
               if($('#applicant-countryOfBirth').length) {
                  clearInterval(interval_2);
              setTimeout(function() {
              fillForm_2(csv[row]);
              },3000);
            }

            }





          functiondropDownVal(id, text) {
          var value = null;
          $(id).each(function() {
            if(this.text.toLowerCase() == text) {
               value = this.value;
               value = value.split(':');
               if(value.length> 1) { 
                 value = value[1];
                    }else {
                value = value[0];
                }
                }
               });

           return value;
             }


             function fillForm_2(data) {
             var scope = angular.element($('#applicant- 
             countryOfBirth')).scope();
              var country = '';
              country = dropDownVal('#applicant-countryOfBirth option', 
              data[5].toLowerCase());

               //scope.applicant.countryOfBirth = country;
                var state = null;
                scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.applicant.countryOfBirth = country;
               scope.updateStateProvince(scope.applicant.countryOfBirth);
               setTimeout(function() {
              if(country == "US" || country == "CD" || country == "MM") {
                state = dropDownVal('#applicant-stateProvinceOfBirth 
                 option', data[6].toLowerCase());
             }

           var citizen = dropDownVal('#applicant-countryOfCitizenship 
           option', data[7].toLowerCase());
           console.log(country + " " + state + " " + citizen);
           scope.applicant.countryOfCitizenship = citizen;
           scope.applicant.stateProvinceOfBirth = state;
           scope.$apply();
           scope.inherited.next();
          });
         });
        }

        var interval_3 = setInterval(fillFormInterval_3, 1000);
        function fillFormInterval_3() {
        if($('.personal-questions').length) {
          clearInterval(interval_3);
          setTimeout(function() {
          fillForm_3(csv[row]);
          },3000);
        }
      }



       function fillForm_3(data) {
       e.applicant.hasMaidenPreviousName = false;
       scope.applicant.hasAliasName = false;
      scope.applicant.hasSameMailingResidentialAddress = true;
      scope.applicant.doYouHaveAuthCode = false;
      scope.applicant.viewEcNearYou = false;
      scope.inherited.next();
       });
     }



    var interval_4 = setInterval(fillFormInterval_4, 1000);
    function fillFormInterval_4() {
     if($('#ue-btn-US').length) {
        clearInterval(interval_4);
         setTimeout(function() {
           fillForm_4(csv[row]);
           },3000);
        }
       }




        function fillForm_4(data) {
        var scope = angular.element($('#applicant-eyeColor')).scope();
        scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.heightFt = parseInt(data[8].substr(0,1));
        scope.heightIn = parseInt(data[8].substr(1,3));
        scope.weightLb = parseInt(data[9]);
        scope.applicant.hairColor = dropDownVal('#applicant-hairColor 
        option', 
        data[10].toLowerCase());
         scope.applicant.eyeColor = dropDownVal('#applicant-eyeColor 
        option', 
         data[11].toLowerCase());
          scope.applicant.gender = dropDownVal('#applicant-gender 
          option', 
          data[12].toLowerCase());
           if(data[13].toLowerCase() == 'mixed race') {
           data[13] = 'Unknown';
           }else if(data[13].toLowerCase() == 'white' || 
           data[13].toLowerCase() == 
            'hispanic') {
             data[13] = 'Caucasian/Latino';   
            }




           scope.applicant.race = dropDownVal('#applicant-race option', 
           data[13].toLowerCase());
           scope.inherited.next();
           });
           }



           var interval_5 = setInterval(fillFormInterval_5, 1000);
           function fillFormInterval_5() {
              if($('#applicant-mailingAddress-country').length) {
            clearInterval(interval_5);
            setTimeout(function() {
            fillForm_5(csv[row]);
          },3000);
          }
          }




           function fillForm_5(data) {
           var scope = angular.element($('#applicant-mailingAddress- 
           country')).scope();

          scope.$apply(function() {
         scope.applicant.mailingAddress = {};
         scope.applicant.mailingAddress.country = "US";
         scope.updateStates('mailingAddress');
         scope.applicant.mailingAddress.addressLine1 = data[14];
         scope.applicant.mailingAddress.addressLine2 = data[15];
         scope.applicant.mailingAddress.city = data[16];
         setTimeout(function() {
         scope.$apply(function() {
         scope.applicant.mailingAddress.state = dropDownVal('#applicant- 
         mailingAddress-state option', data[17].toLowerCase());
         scope.applicant.mailingAddress.postalCode = data[18];
         scope.inherited.next();
         });
        });
        //scope.inherited.next();
        });
        }



      var interval_6 = setInterval(fillFormInterval_6, 1000);
      function fillFormInterval_6() {
         if($('#designatedRecipient-name').length) {
            clearInterval(interval_6);
            setTimeout(function() {
            fillForm_6(csv[row]);
           },3000);
          }
         }




         function fillForm_6(data) {
         var scope = angular.element($('#designatedRecipient- 
             name')).scope();

        scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.applicant.designatedRecipientName = "BIOVERIFY INC";
        scope.applicant.designatedRecipientAddress = {};
        scope.applicant.designatedRecipientAddress.country = "US";
        scope.applicant.designatedRecipientAddress.addressLine1 = "2535 
        Manana 
        Dr.";
        scope.applicant.designatedRecipientAddress.city = "Dallas";




         setTimeout(function() {
          scope.$apply(function() {
           scope.applicant.designatedRecipientAddress.state = 
           dropDownVal('#applicant-designatedRecipientAddress-state 
           option', 'texas');
           scope.applicant.designatedRecipientAddress.postalCode = 
            "75220";
         scope.inherited.next();
          });
          });
       scope.updateStates();
      });
     }

      var interval_7 = setInterval(fillFormInterval_7, 1000);
      function fillFormInterval_7() {
           if($('#payment-nameOnCard').length) {
       clearInterval(interval_7);
       setTimeout(function() {
       fillForm_7(csv[row]);
        },3000);
       }
     }

      function fillForm_7(data) {
      var scope = angular.element($('#payment-nameOnCard')).scope();

     scope.$apply(function() {
      scope.applicant.payment.nameOnCard = "Brendan J Berrells";
      scope.applicant.payment.cardNumber = "4246315197117185";
      scope.applicant.payment.expiration = {};
      scope.applicant.payment.expiration.month = 11;
      scope.applicant.payment.expiration.year = "19";
      scope.applicant.payment.csc = "255";

       });
      }


   });
```

Comment: what is GM_getResourceText ? , there is any documentation for it?

Comment: This is an  API method which loads an external resource, such as an external JavaScript routine,

Comment: if it's some API so need to check this API, did you checked? can you send link to this API?